# Keras Prediction after test values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently trying to build neuronal network to be able to predict time series, but the question is, is it possible to predict further than just the test dataset. I mean, for my example, I have a dataset of about 3000 values, from which I keep 90% for training and 10% for testing. Then When I compare the prediction with the actual test value, it corresponds, but is it possible for instance to ask the  program to predict the next 500 values (i.e. from 3001 to 3500) ?

Here is a snipper of the code I use.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM, GRU
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import optimizers
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
import time
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (-1, 1))


def load_data(datasetname, column, seq_len, normalise_window):
    # A support function to help prepare datasets for an RNN/LSTM/GRU
    data = datasetname.loc[:,column]

    sequence_length = seq_len + 1
    result = []
    for index in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
        result.append(data[index: index + sequence_length])

    result = np.array(result)
    result.reshape(-1,1)
    training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(result)

    print (result)
    #Last 10% is used for validation test, first 90% for training
    row = round(0.9 * training_set_scaled.shape[0])
    train = training_set_scaled[:int(row), :]
    #np.random.shuffle(train)
    x_train = train[:, :-1]
    y_train = train[:, -1]
    X_test = training_set_scaled[int(row):, :-1]
    y_test = training_set_scaled[int(row):, -1]
    print ("shape train", x_train)
    print ("shape train", X_test)
    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))  

    return [x_train, X_test, y_train, y_test]


def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    layers = {'input': 100, 'hidden1': 150, 'hidden2': 256, 'hidden3': 100, 'output': 10}

    model.add(LSTM(
            50, 
            return_sequences=True, 

            input_shape=(200,1)
            ))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(
            layers['hidden2'],
            return_sequences=True,
           ))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(
            layers['hidden3'],
            return_sequences=False,
            ))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Activation("linear"))

    model.add(Dense(
            output_dim=layers['output']))


    start = time.time()
    model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam")
    print ("Compilation Time : ", time.time() - start)
    return model

dataset = pd.read_csv(
    'data.csv')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = load_data(dataset, 'mean anomaly', 200, False)
model = build_model()
print ("train",X_train)
print ("test",X_test)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=256, epochs=1,  validation_split=0.05)
predictions =  model.predict(X_test)
predictions = np.reshape(predictions, (predictions.size,))
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(311)
plt.title("Actual Test Signal w/Anomalies & noise")
plt.plot(y_test)
plt.subplot(312)
plt.title("predicted signal")
plt.plot(predictions, 'g')
plt.subplot(313)
plt.title("training signal")
plt.plot(y_train, 'b')
plt.plot(y_test, 'y')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'])
plt.show()
```

I have read that I should increase the output dim of the dense layer to get more than 1 predicted value, or increase the size of my window in the load data function ?

Here is the result, the yellow plot is supposed to be after the blue one, it respresents my input test data, the first plot is a zoom on this data and the second one the prediction.
[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to predict the output value of your serie at *t+x* based on data at time *t*, the data you need to feed to the network should already have this format.

#### Time series data formating :

If you have 3000 data point and want to predict the output value for the next "virtual" 500 point you should offset the output value by this amount. For exemple :

In your dataset, your 500th data point correspond to the 500th output value. If you want to predict "future" values then the 500th data point should have the 1000th output value. You can do this in pandas with the [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) function. Be aware that you will loose the last 500 data point by doing so, has they will no longer have an output value.

Then when you predict on data point xi you'll have the output value yi+500. You should find some basic guides for time serie forecasting on sites like [machinelearningmastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/)

#### Good pratice for model evaluation :

If you want to better evaluate the quality of your model, first find some metrics that suits your problem and try to increase test set percenatage. While graphics are a good way to visualise result, they can be deceiving, try combining them with some metrics ! (be carefull with Mean Squarred Error, it can give you a biased score with value in the range [-1;1] as the square of an error in this range will always be less than the acutal error, try Mean Absolute Error instead)

#### Data leakage when scalling data :

While scalling data is usually a good thing you need to be carefull doing so. You comited something called a data leak. You used scalling on the whole data set before splitting into training and test set. Further reading about this [data leak](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/).

#### Update

I think i misunderstood your problem.

If you want to "predict further than just the test dataset" you will need some unseen/new data to make more prediction. The test set is only made to evaluate the performance of the learning phase.

Now if you want to predict further than just the next step (this won't allow you to "predict further than just the test dataset" because of the way you change your dataset, see bellow) :
Your model as it's made will only ever predict the next step.

In your example you feed to the algorithm series of lenght 'seq_len' and give them as output the value right after the end of those series. If you want your algorithm to learn to predict in more than one step into the future you y_train must have value at the corresponding time in the future, example :

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...]
seq_len = 5
step_to_predict = 5
```

So to predict not one step into the future but five, your series will have to look like this :

```
x_serie_1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
y_serie_1 = [9]
x_serie_2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
y_serie_2 = [10]
```

This is a way to get your model to learn how to make predictions further into the future than just the next step.

Comment: I tried to do this : forecast = shift(X_test, -500, cval=np.NaN)
but the output is a array full of NaN values...

Comment: Usage of shift is usually like this :
your_dataframe['column_to_shift'] = your_dataframe['column_to_shift'].shift(-500). 

You will then have to drop the last value rows as they won't have any value anymore :

 your_dataframe = your_dataframe[:len(your_dataframe)-500]. By the way, is the time between each data point always the same ? ( one hour, one minute etc...)

Comment: I only have one column for now, and what I would like to do to be clearer, I would like the green plot to be let's say forcasted 500 values into the future, and showing margin of error. So in the end the test dataset would only be 300 values but the prediction would go to 800.

Comment: I succeeded shifting the array by using :  np.vstack((np.zeros((2,)+X_test.shape[1:], dtype=X_test.dtype), X_test))
but I had a array of size 293 and I still have the same size after the shifting, which mean I lost the values and I think what I should get is an array of size 793 (293 + 500) right ? then I would make my prediction on this larger array

Comment: Not really, do you suggest that when I prepare my sliding windows from my dataset, I should change the sequence length ? (i.e. sequence_length = seq_len + nbelementsinfuturetopredict ?)